# SSH session keeps exiting my terminal

Tags: raspbian, ssh, raspbian-wheezy, apt

I have set up my Raspberry PI though [these instructions](http://www.penguintutor.com/linux/raspberrypi-headless) and was able to connect to it through SSH. I have installed RASPBIAN WHEEZY.

However, when I run `sudo apt-get update` it keeps closing the whole terminal. I am connecting to PI through Ubuntu Desktop machine. I am not sure why this is happening. Any ideas?

Comment: does it do the same when logged in directly (not via SSH)?

Comment: I haven't been able to test that as I have no USB keyboard right now :s I also see the same behaviour on some other commends like `apt-get install` on some circumstances.

Comment: what else is connected to your Pi and how are you powering it?

Comment: nothing else, it's powered through the 5v MicroUSB input. Is there any logs that I can check for this? It's specifically happening on `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: you could check the logs in /var/log especially the apt logs which are in /var/log/apt

Comment: I tried it in a different client (in Windows, through Git Bash) and it works nicely now. I guess it was a client issue rather than a server. Didn't expected this :s will check the logs anyway.

Answer (score 2):

If it is a timeout issue (although usually the timeout should be long enough at least for a `dist-upgrade`; how long does yours take?), then you can configure a keepalive in your SSH config file by adding

```
Host *
    ServerAliveInterval 60
```

to the file `~/.ssh/config`. See also [Keep SSH session alive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25084288/keep-ssh-session-alive) and [How does tcp-keepalive work in ssh?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34004/how-does-tcp-keepalive-work-in-ssh). The fact that it works from a different client suggests it is in fact a timeout issue.

Otherwise, it might be helpful to add `-vvv` to ssh and see the debug output:

```
ssh -vvv pi@192.168.1.6
```

Have you configured a static IP for your raspberry? In that case, could it clash with the IP of your Ubuntu machine? (See the output of `/sbin/ifconfig` of both machines.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have this issue with Putty connection to Raspbian from MS-Windows, however, you may have this issue on other platforms. Indeed on UBUNTU this was a common case.

On Putty, Change Setting, click on 'Connection' and modify the 'KeepAlive' options. Open the configuration panel and click on Connection and enable 'TCP_KEEPALIVE' sending 'Null packets' every 30 seconds

Now that you are there click on 'Window' ->  'Translation' and select Latin-1, works nice with Raspbian character graphics.

Go back to 'Session', click on a name and 'save' the configuration.

[image: Putty Setup]